# How do i make Font stick next to username

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

Using Fontawesome font and I had to make it a hyperlink to even out the height..so **how do i get the icon right beside the hello tim@test?**

When I put the font in the same li as the user name it looks like this..

[image]

```
<li>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user" style="color:green"></i></a> @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
        </li>
```

and inline:

[image]

```
<li><div style="display:inline">
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user" style="color:green"></i></a> @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
            </div>
        </li>
```

When I use it as a separate li I'm closer to what i want but its still not right beside it like I'd like:
[image]

```
 <li>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user" style="color:green"></i></a>
        </li>
```

Full Code:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity

@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user" style="color:green"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li>
             @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
    </ul>
    }
}
else
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
    </ul>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Html.ActionLink` simply makes an `A` element for you... all of the `@Html` methods do things like this... in your second example you were putting an anchor in another anchor.

In this case, you need more control of the content... in this case `@Url.Route` is what you want to inject the controller/action's route only into the `A` element, while the icon is inside, along with the rest of your content.

---

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity

@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
      <a href="@Url.Route("Index", "Manage")" title="Manage">
        <i class="fa fa-user" style="color:green"></i>
        Hello @User.Identity.GetUserName()!
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { style: "display:inline;" }))
      {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="this.parentNode.submit();">
          Log off
        </a>
      }
    </li>
  </ul>
} else {
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
  </ul>
}
```

Other changes include, moving the logoff form to simply wrap the link, and adjust the link's action to target the parent... your assigning of `navbar-right` to the form probably borked things a little too.  The form as above doesn't need an id for reference, as it's the `parentNode` to the Logoff link.

Comment: Your code does this which fixes my problem but makes log off off center vertically: http://puu.sh/lXbhw/cc7a2545ef.png

Comment: You need to tweak your form's style... you'd need to check what the display attributes of the `LI` and `A` tag that are vertically aligned look like... possibly form's style as `display:block; margin: auto`